# Unable to grant additional AWS roles the ability to interact with my cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to learn AWS EKS and following [Getting started with Amazon EKS – AWS Management Console and AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html) guide step by step except for the region which I have changed to us-east-1.

I am able to create my cluster - `my-cluster` but when I am trying to configure my computer which is an EC2 instance (T2.Micro) to communicate with the cluster, I get `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)` error. On deep diving, I found that the EC2 role (ARN - arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ec2-admin) needs to assume the role that created the cluster (ARN - arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myAmazonEKSClusterRole). I made these modifications in the role definition as well by modifying Trust Relationship in `myAmazonEKSClusterRole` getting `arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/myAmazonEKSClusterRole/test-session` After this, I am able to execute `aws eks` commands but `kubectl` commands are still eluding me.

For executing `kubectl` commands, I am trying to follow steps in [Managing users or IAM roles for your cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html). However, they are asking me to make changes to `aws-auth-cm.yaml` configMap file which I can't do because I am unable to execute `kubectl apply` command.

My `kubeconfig` file -

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <cert>
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster/my-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster/my-cluster
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster/my-cluster
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster/my-cluster
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster/my-cluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster/my-cluster
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - my-cluster
      command: aws
```

The contents of aws-auth-cm.yaml file after I made the changes are

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
          #    - rolearn: <ARN of instance role (not instance profile)>
          #      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
          #      groups:
          #        - system:bootstrappers
          #        - system:nodes
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::375712918983:role/myAmazonEKSClusterRole
      username: myAmazonEKSClusterRole
      groups:
        - system:masters
```

Can you please help with this or give some pointers?

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You will want one of 3 things; either:

- assume the `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myAmazonEKSClusterRole` in a terminal session such that the `aws eks get-token` run by `kubectl` will behave correctly
- create an awscli profile that assumes the `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myAmazonEKSClusterRole` role and update the `args:` to include `[..., "--profile", "whatever-you-call-that-profile",...]`
- or assume the role in a terminal, run `aws eks get-token`, and put that static credential in your kubeconfig since it doesn't seem you need the credential for very long just to update that ConfigMap

For the first one, I mean `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myAmazonEKSClusterRole ... | tee sts-creds.json` and then `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= AWS_SECRET_KEY= AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=` based on the contents of that json

For the second one, I mean:

```sh
$ cat >> $HOME/.aws/config <<FOO
[profile my-cluster]
assume_role = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myAmazonEKSClusterRole
source_profile = whatever
; or credential_source = whatever
FOO
```

according to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)

Comment: I tried the first step but in futility. For the third step, where should I substitute the credential in kubeconfig?

Comment: `kubectl config set-credential tmp --token "$here" && kubectl config set-context --current --user tmp`

Comment: I made these changes and then changed the aws-auth-cm.yaml file as well (attached in the question). Executed `kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml` and got the error `error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)`

Comment: (a) you **FOR SURE** do not want to remove that instance profile mapping or Nodes won't join your cluster (b) and even if you did, don't use mixed indentation like that, since yaml is very picky about whitespace (c) did you check `kubectl get nodes` before that `apply` to ensure your `aws eks get-token` did as it should?

Comment: I checked `kubectl get svc` and `get all`. Both of them weren't working. Since I didn't get around to creating nodes (because that step wasn't covered in AWS Tutorial till where I reached), I commented out the nodes arn part in the yaml file.